# Creating an SSIS job to split a column and insert into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a column called `Description`:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                Description/Title                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Liszt, Hungarian Rhapsody #6 {'Pesther Carneval'}; 2 Episodes from Lenau's 'Faust'; 'Hunnenschlacht' Symphonic Poem. (NW German Phil./ Kulka)                                                                                                   |
| Beethoven, Piano Sonatas 8, 23 & 26. (Justus Frantz)                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| Puccini, Verdi, Gounod, Bizet: Arias & Duets from Butterfly, Tosca, Boheme, Turandot, I Vespri, Faust, Carmen. (Fiamma Izzo d'Amico & Peter Dvorsky w.Berlin Radio Symph./Paternostro)                                                          |
| Puccini, Ponchielli, Bizet, Tchaikovsky, Donizetti, Verdi: Arias from Boheme, Manon Lescaut, Tosca, Gioconda, Carmen, Eugen Onegin, Favorita, Rigoletto, Luisa Miller, Ballo, Aida. (Peter Dvorsky, ten. w.Hungarian State Opera Orch./ Mihaly) |
| Thomas, Leslie: 'The Virgin Soldiers' (Hywel Bennett reads abridged version. Listening time app. 2 hrs. 45 mins. DOLBY)                                                                                                                         |
| Katalsky, A. {1856-1926}: Liturgy for A Cappella Chorus. Rachmaninov, 6 Choral Songs w.Piano. (Bolshoi Theater Children's Choir/ Zabornok. DOLBY)                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please note that above I'm only showing 1 field.

Also, the output that I would like is:

```
+-------+-------+
| Word  | Count |
+-------+-------+
| Arias |     3 |
| Duets |     2 |
| Liszt |    10 |
| Tosca |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```

I want this output to encompass EVERY record. I do not want a separate one of these for each record, just one global one.

I am choosing to use SSIS to do this job. **I'd like your input on which controls to use to help with this task:**

[image]

I'm not looking for a solution, but simply some direction on how to get started with this. I understand this can be done many different ways, but I cannot seem to think of a way to do this most efficiently. Thank you for any guidance.

FYI:

This script does an excellent job of concatenating everything:

```
select description + ', ' as 'data()' 
from [BroincInventory] 
for xml path('')
```

But I need guidance on how to work with this result to create the required output. How can this be done with c# or with one of the SSIS components?

**edit:** As siyual points out below I need a script task. The script above obviously will not work since there's a limit to the size of a data point.

Comment: Honestly, the best bet for something like this is to use a `Script Component` using C#/VB to process the data into new rows, adding to the output buffer.

Comment: You want to count each occurrence of each word in every row for a specific column?  I would just split it on ' ', and write each word out as a row in a table.  Then just count the words.  You may need to use regular expressions to filter out (or strip out) punctuation and such.

Comment: @Siyual could you help with that

Answer (score 1):

I think term extraction might be the component you are looking for.  Check this out: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3194/simple-text-mining-with-the-ssis-term-extraction-component/

Comment: though unfortunately it doesnt pay attention to numbers!

Comment: this would be absolutely perfect if it could include numbers